# Problem with placeholder on a django template input form field

Tags: html, django, forms, authentication, django-templates

I am creating a user login using the default django authentication system.

Using a bootstrap template, I am creating a form with custom fields, and they are working correctly.

The problem is that when displaying this form, it renders showing the value attribute instead of the placeholder that I have passed to it.

This is who it looks:
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PtkZ.png)

**login.html**

```
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
      <img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com"
          value="{{form.username}}">
        <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password"
          value="{{form.password}}">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me &emsp; <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">
            Lost password?</a>
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2022 all rights deserved</p>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can use django authentication form and override it in your `forms.py`, if you want, how to do it, let me know.While working with django, it is better to use `Form API`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `{{ form.username }}` you are sending the `str(form.username)` to the value attribute. The `__str__` method of the form field renders the HTML. That is why you're seeing what you're seeing.

To fix this, you could put `{{ form.username.initial }}` to display the initial value of the field.

Tip: try using crispy forms for rendering forms. It is way easier and makes a more compact syntax which depends on the form code, not on the HTML. See https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Another thing, I think you're missing the `name` attribute on the input fields. Not sure if this works without it.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But this doesn´t fix placeholder problem. Using initial, the initial value showing on field is None

Comment: You can use `{{ form.username.initial|default:'' }}` in case the field does not have a value.

Comment: Also, maybe it's simpler to let the form render it self by completely removing your `<input>` tag and using `{{ form.username }}` instead of it. See the documentation for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: The thing is that I need to show the placeholder, but value overwrites it

Comment: Maybe this helps: `{% if form.username.initial %}value={{ form.username.initial }}{% endif %}`. So, no value is specified if the initial value is not set.

Comment: I have tried, but it still does not show the placeholder

Comment: Are you talking about the "name@example.com" value?

Comment: yeah! I tried to put it into the default initial value, but don`t work like a placeholder

Comment: If there is a value set, the placeholder will not be shown.

Comment: Do you want to show possible initial values in the form? I mean actual values, not placeholders? If not, you can just remove the value attribute

Comment: Yes, I have thought about it. I think I'll look into the crispy forms because the template doesn't work until the form is used in some way, and if I remove the value, I won't be using the form at all.

Comment: Ideally, you should use crispy forms - simply use `{% crispy form %}` in the template. And in the Django code you should create a LoginForm which specifies field attribute (`placeholder='name@example.org'`). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django for more details. What you're doing seems like a quick and dirty solution, but it can get very complicated when you're a newby to Django. Reading the official docs and implementing it properly could save you a lot of troubles.